# Consume/Subscribe custom events of class module

Tags: excel, vba, oop, events

I want to consume an event of a class module that I have written.
The class module looks like this

```
''CError64Row
Public Event ErrorClicked(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)

Public WithEvents lblDescription As MSForms.Label
Public WithEvents lblFile As MSForms.Label
Public WithEvents lblRow As MSForms.Label
Public WithEvents lblCol As MSForms.Label

Public row As Long
Public col As Long

Private Sub lblDescription_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   RaiseEvent ErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub

Private Sub lblFile_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   RaiseEvent ErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub

Private Sub lblRow_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   RaiseEvent ErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub

Private Sub lblCol_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   RaiseEvent ErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub
```

In one of my forms I create the `CError64Row` objects

```
Private m_Elements As Long

Private mErrors() As CError64Row

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    m_Elements = 0
End Sub

Public Function SetError(text As String, filename As String, row As Integer, column As Integer) As String
    Dim ctl As control

   ReDim Preserve mErrors(m_Elements + 1)

    Dim errorRow As CError64Row
    Set errorRow = New CError64Row
    Set mErrors(m_Elements) = errorRow

    mErrors(m_Elements).row = row
    mErrors(m_Elements).col = column
    Set mErrors(m_Elements).lblDescription = Me.Controls.Add("forms.label.1")
    With mErrors(m_Elements).lblDescription
        .Left = 35
        .height = 14
        .Top = 18 + (m_Elements) * 14
        .width = 631
        .Caption = text
    End With

    Set mErrors(m_Elements).lblFile = Me.Controls.Add("forms.label.1")
    With mErrors(m_Elements).lblFile
        .Left = 665
        .height = 14
        .Top = 18 + (m_Elements) * 14
        .width = 106
        .Caption = filename
    End With

    Set mErrors(m_Elements).lblRow = Me.Controls.Add("forms.label.1")
    With mErrors(m_Elements).lblRow
        .Left = 770
        .height = 14
        .Top = 18 + (m_Elements) * 14
        .width = 36
        .Caption = CStr(row)
    End With

    Set mErrors(m_Elements).lblCol = Me.Controls.Add("forms.label.1")
    With mErrors(m_Elements).lblCol
        .Left = 805
        .height = 14
        .Top = 18 + (m_Elements) * 14
        .width = 36
        .Caption = CStr(column)
    End With
    m_Elements = m_Elements + 1
End Function

Public Sub CError64Row_ErrorClicked(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)
    MsgBox "MSG received"
End Sub
```

I want to receive the ErrorClicked event but I am not sure how to subscribe to the event.
I read in this answer [Is it possible to create and handle a custom Event in a Customized UserForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660399/is-it-possible-to-create-and-handle-a-custom-event-in-a-customized-userform) that I can "subscribe" via

> Private Sub [Provider]_MemberName

but I doubt that this works with an object which is created in a method.
How can I subscribe to an event of an object which was created in a method?

Comment: What I believe you need is to declare you mErrors variable using WithEvents `Private WithEvents mErrors As CError64Row`. Unfortunately, you can't do this and have it be an array. A workaround I used was to have a mediator class module that acted as an event emitter that could store your array. See my GitHub repository with an example of it [Userform-EventListener](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Userform-EventListener). This might even help with what you are doing.

Comment: @RobertTodar it's simpler than that... the `CError64Row` already has an indirect reference to the form, so there's no need for it to raise/forward any events - it can just invoke a method on the parent form directly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for making it simpler. As a follow-up on my response, is this ever a valid way of going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Private mErrors() As CError64Row
> ```

Your "event provider" objects are in this `mErrors` array - you would need to somehow declare it `WithEvents`, but this would be illegal:

```
Private WithEvents mErrors() As CError64Row
```

The problem isn't that the object is created in a method - how the object is created makes no difference. The problem is that you have no way to make the form handle events forwarded by an object whose reference resides in an array/collection and not a `Private WithEvents` field.

The solution is to make the custom class talk to the form - and you already have a reference to it:

```
Private Sub lblDescription_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim parentForm As TheFormClass
    Set parentForm = lblDescription.Parent
    parentForm.HandleErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub
```

Now, this is tightly coupling the `TheFormClass` form with the custom control class, and this isn't ideal - what if we need to reuse that class in another form?

We could go late-bound:

```
Private Sub lblDescription_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim parentForm As Object
    Set parentForm = lblDescription.Parent
    parentForm.HandleErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub
```

But then we lose compile-time validation and there's no guarantee that the `parentForm` has a `HandleErrorClicked` method - and if the method isn't there, we'll blow up with error 438.

Unless... unless we formalize that with an interface, like a very simple `IErrorView` class, which might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HandleErrorClicked(ByVal row As Long, ByVal col As Long)
End Sub
```

...and make the form class implement this interface:

```
Implements IErrorView

Private Sub IErrorView_HandleErrorClicked(ByVal row As Long, ByVal col As Long)
    ' there's the handler!
End Sub
```

And now the custom control class can work with any form that implements the `IErrorView` interface, and we get compile-time validation back:

```
Private Sub lblDescription_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim parentForm As IErrorView
    Set parentForm = lblDescription.Parent
    parentForm.HandleErrorClicked(row, col)
End Sub
```